# FIx color banding in unity

Tags: unity

I create archviz in oculus using unity. I didn't use any texture, just simple solid white color. But inside the room there is gradient from light to dark where i can see the color banding. i'm using baked GI and a single directional light. This banding effect is visible in 3d scene window and when i run on oculus as well.

What setting do i have to modify to fix it ?

Comment: Are you using HDR color?

Comment: Banding on areas of greyscale gradient is a pretty pervasive problem in games. With a low-dynamic-range output, you've got only 256 distinct levels to play with. If you have a smooth surface larger than 256 pixels (or less for lower-contrast gradients), you're going to see stair-steps where the level plateaus for a few pixels before dropping to the next plateau. [The developers of Inside had to apply quite a lot of sophisticated noise and dithering into their rendering in order to achieve their smooth-looking low-contrast gradients](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdN06E6Xn9E&t=17m)

Comment: Adding to @DMGregory 's comment: This issue can be greatly amplified by sRGB conversion, gamma correction, and various layered post-effects. The multiple rounding errors accumulate very quickly to trash the final color precision from 8bits down to effectively 5 or 6 bits.Throw in multi-layered foggy blurred backgrounds through a water surface reflection effect and it can be down to 3-4 bits/channel effective when looking at the water. The baked GI could also cause banding if the GI texture is compressed.